# how to make a random number a multiple of 25

Tags: python, random

I am working on a snake game where I want the apple to randomize its x and y coordinates, but it doesn't align with my background (a 20x20 grid).

I have tried to grab a number between 0 and 20 then multiply it by 25, however, eventually, it would randomly disappear.

Is there a way to make a random integer a multiple of a preset number?

if it helps, here's my code:

```
# import library/libraries
import pygame as pg
import time
import random as r
pg.init ()

# creates the window
display = pg.display.set_mode ((500, 500))
pg.display.set_caption ("snake")

# snake
snake_x = 250
snake_y = 250
snake_x_change = 0
snake_y_change = 0
snake_x_size = 25
snake_y_size = 25
t = time.time ()

# apple
apple_x = 375
apple_y = 250
apple_x_size = 25
apple_y_size = 25

# definitions

def snake (x, y):
    pg.draw.rect (display, (0, 100, 0), pg.Rect (x, y, snake_x_size, snake_y_size))

def apple (x, y):
    pg.draw.rect (display, (100, 0, 0), pg.Rect (x, y, apple_x_size, apple_y_size))


# keeps the window open
execute = True
while execute:
    # sets window color (red, green, blue)
    display.fill ((0, 0, 0))
    # events
    for event in pg.event.get ():
        # checks if the X button has been pressed
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            execute = False
        # checks if a button is being held
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_w:
                snake_y_change = -25
                snake_x_change = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_a:
                snake_x_change = -25
                snake_y_change = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_s:
                snake_y_change = 25
                snake_x_change = 0
            if event.key == pg.K_d:
                snake_x_change = 25
                snake_y_change = 0
    # moves actors
    if time.time() > t + 0.1:
        t = time.time()
        snake_x = snake_x + snake_x_change
        snake_y = snake_y + snake_y_change
    # collision stuff
    if snake_x <= 0:
        snake_x = 0
    if snake_y <= 0:
        snake_y = 0
    if snake_x >= 475:
        snake_x = 475
    if snake_y >= 475:
        snake_y = 475
    if snake_x == apple_x and snake_y == apple_y:
        apple_x = r.randint (0, 20)
        apple_y = r.randint (0, 20)
        apple_x = apple_x * 25
        apple_y = apple_y * 25
    # loads actors
    snake (snake_x, snake_y)
    apple (apple_x, apple_y)
    # updates game window
    pg.display.flip ()
```

Comment: Sample x from (0, 20), sample y from (0, 20).

Comment: Pick a random int and multiply it by 25.

Comment: The code in the question is not runnable. Please provide code that is runnable and error-free. Unless the error which occurs is the error for which the solution is sought. This might get rid of some downvotes. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provides information to help you succeed.

Comment: @khelwood that worked at first, but eventually the apple would just randomly dissapear.

Comment: @Priscan791 Post a [mre] demonstrating that problem and perhaps someone will tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Now the code goes way beyond the question, "how to make a random number a multiple of 25". Some might now be offended just adding 84 lines of code which now produce **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'** message.  This is not an example of a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Carl_M I don't know how the module error got there, as the code works for me. note that I said "import pygame as pg" instead of just "import pygame", also make sure you have the pygame library installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that a number is multiple of 20, you could do this:

```
apple_x = 20 * r.randint (0, 475)
apple_y = 20 * r.randint (0, 475)
```

Pay attention to the max number that you can accept and adjust the rand interval.

Comment: there is a problem, as the apple eventually disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can round it to the nearest 20 or 25.

```py
apple_x = r.randint(0, round(475/20)*20)
```

Whichever it is, you have me confused. You say you want a multiple of 25, but the grid is 20x20.

Comment: It is off centred and also disappears.

Comment: Set the 20s to 25s then

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the apple would disappear.
the x/y coordinate of a rectangle or image is always in the top right corner.

so instead of multiplying it by 20, you actually have to multiply it by 19.
sorry everyone, sorry for the confusion.